# Does svg-edit retain arbitrary attributes

Tags: svg, svg-edit

Using svg-edit and some of the variants I've found that seem like they are based on the same JS libraries, I create a basic drawing then using either source editor within svg-edit, or loading up an external Notepad-created SVG, that some attributes on `<g>` elements for example are tossed out.

I want to amend a typical element with let's say a `class="Position"` it works, and retains the attribute through edit cycles.  But when I use `foo="bar"` that attribute seems to get discarded completely.

This is fairly inconvenient because I want to use svg-edit to create an arbitrary drawing with some unique-to-me attributes that my code can later recognize.

Is this a dumb question?  Am I missing something fundamental about SVGs with arbitrary non-standard type attributes included (and for retention)?

Comment: Oh maybe I should try a `data-` prefix on my attributes, I read somewhere this is a way to isolate non-standard type attributes.

Comment: data- is mostly for html (or SVG in html), for XML (standalone SVG) the usual mechanism for foreign content is namespaces.